# How to make additional data available to ApiController method via Attribute (AuthorizeAttribute)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Our Web API will require consumers of the API to provide an API key we assign to them. The API key will be used for authorization and will be used to add data (somewhere, somehow) so that the ApiController's methods will have access to them.

I'm considering creating an AuthorizationAttribute that

- checks that the API key is present
- verifies the supplied API key is valid for the incoming request (referrer)
- *If the API key is present and valid, it will be used to get data such as ClientId and ClientName and add it to the incoming Request's Properties collection for use by methods in the ApiController. We might encode the ClientId, etc. into the API key and decode it server-side or retrieve it from the database.*

In my dummied-up custom AuthorizationAttribute, if authorization succeeds, I add clientId and clientName to the current Request by doing the following:

```
actionContext.Request.Properties.add("clientId", 1234);
actionContext.Request.Properties.add("clientName", "Super Client");
```

Then within a method in the ApiController I grab the data by using:

```
int clientId = (int)Request.Properties["clientId"];
string clientName = (string)Request.Properties["clientName"];
```

This works, but it assumes that "clientId" and "clientName" exists in `Request.Properties`. We can do checks with `Request.Properties.ContainsKey` but I don't want to repeat this checking code in every method in our Web API. I suppose I can have yet another attribute that does the check and if it fails to find them in `Request.Properties` returns a 500 Internal Server Error (Bad Request 400?).

Or we could have the AuthorizationAttribute perform the authorization and then make a single call - in each ApiController method - to return an Client object with the data required given the API key supplied in the JSON payload. At this point we know the API key is valid so we'll get data the controller requires to process the request.

What is a recommended approach for adding data to the Request for access by our ApiController's methods? Data that is required but is based off a valid API key being supplied (either we'll grab the data from the database or it'll be encoded into the public API key and decoded on our server). And that will:

- preferably not violate DRY (checking that the data the ApiController requires has been added and their respective values the right type)
- ensures that the values are present and the methods can execute without raising an exception
- should this be broken into two attributes? One that does the authorization, the next that gets the data needed based on the supplied API key?

We are running Visual Studio 2010, MVC 4, .NET 4. The API key is to be supplied as part of a JSON payload to the web api.

Magic strings will go away  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ActionFilters, I would suggest using a MessageHandler.  The MessageHandler can look into the request, extract the ClientId and ClientName if they are there and add them to the properties.   Then in the controllers that where you need to pull out that information you can use ApiController extension methods to access the controller.Request.Properties.  This will encapsulate all your magic strings.

I would also suggest putting the APIKey in the Authorization header instead of in a JSON payload as that is exactly what the Authorization header is designed for.

Comment: @DarrellMiller I found an [article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/api-key-user-aspnet-web-api) where the author mentions the Authorization header. Is this along the lines you suggest?

Comment: @DarrellMiller I see one of my points was not worded properly (I have revised and set it in italics in the question). ClientId and ClientName won't be part of the Request, they will be retrieved based on the incoming Api Key. Either encoded into the API key we supply the client or we'll retrieve them from the database. So you are suggesting creating an extension method to inspect that they are present in Request.Properties and successfully converted (string -> int for ClientId)?

Comment: @emgee Yes. You could also use some kind of attribute and action filter to inspect the request properties.  However, I would tend towards using a message handler for processing the API Key because it will be provided for every request.

Comment: Here's a link to [HTTP Message Handlers on ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) that goes into more detail on what DarrellMiller suggested. There is a simple API Key example about 3/4 of the way down.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to give your client a public shared key and a private key. For each request made, the client is required to include their public key as a parameter along with an expiration date. The reason for the expiration date is so the values contributing to their authorization token  will vary per request. Since the client will know the resource they are attempting to access and have their public key handy they only need to be sure the expiration date they send is within an allowance threshold of what the server thinks the time is in utc. Both the server and client can create a secure hash using those values and their supposed private key. You can then validate if the client making the request  -->public key, is who they say they are by using their private key to decrypt the message.

Require a signature for each incoming message. If on the query string it could theoretically look something like this note: you can also use the http header:

```
Signature=<UrlEncode(Base64(HMAC-MD5(LowerCase( AbsolutePath(ResourceURL)) + UTCDate(ExpirationDate,“yyyyMMddHHmmss”)))> &Expires=<UTCDate(ExpirationDate ,“yyyyMMddHHmmss”)>&AccessKey=<PublicAccessKey>
```

For each secure method you define that requires authorization you can let the call go through if the hash is valid, else return a unauthorized http status code.

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking how to create an API key. They are asking where the identifying information should extracted from the key in a manageable way.